# Select data from database table in Yii1

Tags: yii

I want to select data from my feedback table. i write this code to fetch value from DB. but this isn't work. i can do this in Yii2.

```
 $a = Feedback::model()->findAll();

  echo $a->positivecomments;
  echo $a->negativecomments;
  echo $a->immediatecomments;
  echo $a->areas;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Yii1 for  getting all model you can use 
*(I assume your fields are positivecomment, negativecomment, immediatecomment, area)*

```
$a =  Feedback::model()->>findAll();

echo $st->positivecomments;

foreach($a as $key => $value) {
   echo $value->positivecomment;
   echo $value->negativecomment;
   echo $value->immediatecomment;
   echo $value->area;

}
```

the 0 element by

```
echo $a[0]->positivecomment;
echo $a[0]->negativecomment;
echo $a[0]->immediatecomment;
echo $a[0]->area;
```

Comment: don't mixed with the Yii2 coding. i don't have $found value to use in here. check my yii1 coding and help me to get positivecomment field value from the table. my table have 8 fields and i need to show all the fields

Comment: Property "Feedback.negativecomment" is not defined.

Comment: @aselanuwan You need to use whatever your DB column is called. If your DB is called "negativecomments" with an s, then use `$value->negativecomments` with an s.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$st = Feedback::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('module_id' => $found->id));
echo $st->PositiveComment;
```